# Not constructive flag on joke comment declined

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, declined-flags

I flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374444/pick-a-random-number-but-not-the-number-3#comment39569534_25374444) as Not Constructive because it was clearly a joke.  The flag was declined.  Why?

This was the question:

> ### Pick a random number but not the number 3
>
> What would you add to make it so it still picks a random number but
>   not the number 3?
>
> ```
> - (IBAction)Button3
> {
>     int randomviews = rand() % 6;
>     Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomviews];
> }
> ```

The comment was:

> What would I *add*: `rand() % 6 + 10`

Comment: What makes you think that it is a joke?  Read the suggestion again.  See the magic number `10` again and then at the remainder operator -- it might ring some bells.

Comment: Some comments might appear to be _not constructive_.  Doesn't imply that you'd go on a flagging spree.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef I don't notice anything...

Comment: @0xdeadbeef Because of operator precedence this just changes it to rand() % 16, which is not what the OP wanted.  It will still pick 3.

Comment: You could suggest using a pair of parenthesis?

Comment: @0xdeadbeef: 99 mod 16 is 3 (if using parens). Technically it's still constructive though. User is being glib.

Comment: @NobodyNada that's true, but that would make it *inaccurate*, which is not a reason a moderator would remove a flagged comment.

Comment: You honestly flagged for this?  Honestly?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Gone now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment was not a joke. If anything, it was a wake-up call to the author of the question to be *much* more specific with questions.

The answer in the comments is completely correct (although it might need more parentheses depending on the coding language) and would work, but it may not be the *best* solution. Therefore, it is completely constructive since it both answers the question and provides reason for the author to ask better questions.