# Declined flags for joke comment. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Today I stumbled upon an old question and its accepted answer doesn't answer it at all. Below the mentioned answer there are [lots and lots of useless comments filled with jokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#comment1614240_1732454).

Accordingly to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265177/1812322): "Jokes are more appropriate for Meta than the regular site. However, if a comment doesn't add anything of value to the post it's comment on, then you can always just flag it as not constructive".

I flagged the comments as "not constructive", but some flags were denied and I don't know why. What should I do?

Note: There's a [question with a very similar title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269235/not-constructive-flag-on-joke-comment-declined) as this one, but in a very different context.

Comment: There are a lot of comments that really really really need moderation attention; are you sure you can't find any anywhere else but on that answer?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't understand how this justifies not accepting the flags.

Comment: When processing comment flags moderators can only delete or dismiss the flags.  Those comments on that answer aren't hurting anyone, so the flags were dismissed.

Comment: Moderators have a finite amount of time to moderate each day. We'd rather spend that moderating the highest value stuff.  6 year old comments on a 6 year old answer that are highly upvoted doesn't seem like a good place to focus moderator effort.

Comment: Plus, you've probably summoned Tony the Pony now (bonus points if this comment gets flagged)

Comment: We've received 130+ flags on that answer, most of those are declined/dismissed. That answer isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @bluefeet "Those comments on that answer aren't hurting anyone" which doesn't make them constructive.

Comment: @Bonifacio2 That doesn't make removing them constructive.  You were wasting the mods' time, and got a declined flag as a result.  In the future take the time to consider the value of the mods' time when flagging content.

Comment: @Bonifacio2 You asked why they were declined; we're telling you: Don't waste moderator time with low value cleanup. Moderator time is finite. Ask yourself "Is asking a moderator to step in here really the best use of limited time?" Ironically, I've now spent more time in this meta thread than it took me to clean up those comments that really didn't need cleanup in the first place. Going back to work now.

Comment: Don't flag things for the sake of flagging. And recognize that some things are considered historical and should not be touched.

Comment: related: [what is wrong in flagging an answer that has a wrong content format](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260358/839601). "when the question clearly shows "viewed 1207051 times" and answer shows over 4K upvotes, I guess _everything_ is wrong about flagging it. Common sense could tell that these numbers indicate sufficient level attention given to the post already..."

Comment: ...and that's now 132 flags on that answer. A gift that keeps on giving.

Comment: @BradLarson I guess we know they aren't using `sbyte` to store flag counts.

Comment: This should be required reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This particular answer whose comments you're flagging is famous. It's [on a T-shirt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition); it's often referred to as "The Answer". It's a historical artifact at this point. It's so exceptional that a moderator has edited a banner into the body of the post asking people not to flag it!

Your flagging of those comments is sort of like asking a moderator to put a fig leaf over the naughty bits of an ancient statue: maybe this isn't something we want to see on a day-to-day basis, but we make an allowance when viewing a piece of antiquity.

Comment: I had no idea. And no way of knowing.

Comment: Well, there is the lock on the post, and the big highlighted banner at the end of it saying "please don't flag".

Comment: I didn't flag the post. I flagged its comments.

Comment: Fair enough, but I guess I'd say look around just a wee bit more next time before flagging. Context may reveal a better action; then again, it may not.

Comment: The comment says not to flag the post, which implies its because its formatting is actually intended.

Answer (score 5):

> I flagged the comments as "not constructive", but some flags were denied and I don't know why. What should I do?

There is nothing for you to do.

As to why they were declined:

There are a lot of comments that really really really need moderation attention; are you sure you can't find any anywhere else but on that answer?

Put another way:

Moderators have a finite amount of time to moderate each day. We'd rather spend that moderating the highest value stuff. 6 year old comments on a 6 year old answer that are highly upvoted doesn't seem like a good place to focus moderator effort.

Your flags were probably declined because there's really no need to focus on that answer.  It's 6 years old; the comments are just as old, and most of them are highly upvoted.  Clearly if there were a problem with the comments a moderator would have stepped in by now.

However, we do need your help with the myriad of new questions we get every day. That's also where we focus our time.  It's really nice that you want the site to look nice, but when choosing what to flag for moderator attention, think: "Is this the best use of a moderator's limited time?"  If there's any uncertainty there, please don't flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read the ["guide to comment flags"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365) and it doesn't mention the question "Is this the best use of a moderator's limited time?", so I didn't think I should consider this. Next time I'll do.

Comment: While I agree that this particular comment flag was properly declined, I sure don't understand the argument that anything that's not top priority should be declined _ipso facto_ as well.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's understandable; but remember that moderators are meant to be exception handlers.  Bringing things to our attention should be an exceptional action, not the norm.  So if people are bringing things to our attention that aren't exceptional, it's by definition a bad use of our time.

Comment: you probably would benefit from canned decline reason for flags cast over there: "120K question views and 4K answer upvotes could tell that sufficient level attention was given to _everything_ about this post already"

Comment: I have never looked at the age of a comment. I have 1.1k helpful flags, and 8 declined. If comment age really mattered I should be having hundreds of declined flags.